# Angularjs - Resource returning promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-services, angular-components

Please keep in mind that I am a beginner in AngularJS. I followed the tutorial on the angularjs site and tried to apply the things there to my own project.
I am trying to use $resource to get data from a json i am getting from the API like so:

CategoryService:

```
angular.module('core.category') 
.factory('Category', ['$resource', '$http',
    function($resource, $http) {
        return $resource('/api/categories', {}, {
            query: {
              method: 'GET',
              isArray: true
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

Going to the url URL/api/categories return a JSON in this format:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"name","desc":"desc"}]
```

In a component i use this to retrieve the json:

```
self.categories = Category.query();
console.log(self.categories);
```

Instead of getting data in json format i get this in the console:

```
[$promise: Promise, $resolved: false]
```

I have tried this:

```
Category.query().$promise.then(function(data) {
   console.log(data);
});
```

And got this:

```
[$promise: Promise, $resolved: true]
```

Why dosn't this get the data in json? Could it be because i am running a php server? And how can i retrive the data from the API in Json format?

Thanks

Comment: It *will* return a promise/object which will resolve later, since fetching data from the server takes a while. There's nothing wrong here.

Comment: @deceze thanks, but i don't really get what you are saying. How exactly do i get it so that the console logs the json?

Comment: Read section "Returns" under "Usage": https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#usage

Comment: @deceze again, thanks, but i have tried the examples there, but they don't seem to be working.

Comment: if you open `URL/api/categories` in the browser, what do you get?

Comment: @yBrodsky It returns a JSON:   [{"id":1,"name":"name","desc":"desc"}]

Comment: Ok, and now open the chrome console and check the network tab. When you run the code `Category.query().$promise.then( ...etc` what do you see? is the request being made and the response properly returned?

Comment: @yBrodsky what exactly am i lookin for? How is the request supposed to look like in the network tab?

Comment: I've tried the same code as yours and have `[Resource, $promise: Promise, $resolved: true]` (while using `$promise.then`) where first `Resource` element is `{id: 1, name: "name", desc: "desc"}`. So you have to check the actual response of your web server as @yBrodsky assumed.

Comment: have you tried Category.query(function(resp){ console.log(resp)});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've tried the same code as yours and have [Resource, $promise:
>   Promise, $resolved: true] (while using $promise.then) where first
>   Resource element is {id: 1, name: "name", desc: "desc"}. So you have
>   to check the actual response of your web server as @yBrodsky assumed.

Thank you to @yBrodsky and @StanislavKvitash. I have solved the problem. It was a problem with my web server.